# Add and Substract values based on checkbox in php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a simple checkbox form which has three options. I want to calculate the price dynamically and i am not storing these values in a database.

```html
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox"id="option1" wire:click="test" wire:model="additions" value="option1">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="option2" wire:click="test" wire:model="additions" value="option2">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" id="option3" wire:click="test" wire:model="additions" value="option3">
   <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

output in the blade file where i show the value

```
{{ $checkout }}
```

Each option has different prices and i am adding to the `$checkout` to calculate the total.

```php
public $additions = [];
public $checkout = 0;

public function test()
{
    // if (in_array('option1', $this->additions)) {
    //     $this->checkout =+ 10;
    //     Log::info($this->checkout);
    // }
    // if (in_array('option2', $this->additions)) {
    //    $this->checkout += 10;
    //     Log::info($this->checkout);
    // }
    // if (in_array('option3', $this->additions)) {
    //     $this->checkout += 10;
    //     Log::info($this->checkout);
    // }

    if (!empty($this->additions)) {
        foreach ($this->additions as $key => $value) {
            if ($value == 'option1') {
                $this->checkout += 10;
            }

            if ($value == 'option2') {
                $this->checkout += 10;
            } else {
                $this->checkout -= 10;
            }
            
            if ($value == 'option3') {
                $this->checkout += 10;
            } else {
                $this->checkout -= 10;
            }        
        }
        Log::info($this->checkout);
    }
}
```

the prices adds but is not correct. For the example i have 10 for each option so when all three options are checked, the total would be 30 and when two options are checked 20 and so on. What i am getting is all over 60 which is no where near 30.

Any help would be appreaciated.

Edited :
`$this->additions` consists all the checked items. eg: if all three options are selected, `$this->additions` will have `option1,option2,option3` in the array.

Comment: Hard to tell what `$this->additions` contains. Does it have a list of _checked_ items?

Comment: @waterloomatt Yes. `$this->additions` has the list of checked items. It will pass `option1, option2, option3` if all checkboxes are checked

Comment: with a checkbox a value is always getting passed. You'll need to check isset($key) to truly see if the checkbox is getting marked or not. From there you can do the math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your Blade view should only have one root element, so you should wrap the entire thing in a `<div>` tag. This is a Livewire thing, and its rather important as it makes it easier for Livewire to do its DOM-diffing.
Secondly, you don't need both `wire:click` and `wire:model`, as you can use `wire:model` alone and listen to updates to the bound field through the `updated()` lifecycle hook - or specifically listen for the `additions` property through `updatedAdditions()`.

Then, when you perform your action, you should be resetting the counter for each iteration and avoid subtracting - otherwise, you will increment the checkout-counter for each click - which is partially what you're seeing now.

The better alternative here is to use a lookup-array that contains the values of each option, and aggregate on that.

```html
<div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="option1" wire:model="additions" value="option1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="option2" wire:model="additions" value="option2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="option3" wire:model="additions" value="option3">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="option1">Option 3</label>
    </div>

    {{ $checkout }}
</div>
```

```php
class Checkout extends Component
{
    public $additions = [];
    public $checkout = 0;

    public function updatedAdditions($value)
    {
        // Declare valid options and the value they increment
        $optionValues = [
            'option1' => 10,
            'option2' => 10,
            'option3' => 10,
        ];

        // Reset the counter before we iterate over the current additions
        $this->checkout = 0;

        // Iterate over additions, and find the value from $validOptions
        // If it doesn't exist in $validOptions, default to 0 (adding 0 makes no difference)
        foreach ($this->additions as $key => $value) {
            $this->checkout += $optionValues[$value] ?? 0;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.checkout');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the logic and the help. I had the checkbox list inside a form. Seems i have to check livewire documentation on the `updated()` lifecycle hook.